# Simplex algorithm calculation time exponential rise

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I am building an energy-system-model with `python/pyomo`. It is basically creating an optimization problem (**LP**) in following form:

```
min cost
st constraint[t]
```

and with the rise of the index t (refering timesteps in the picture), it is creating more constraints for the opt. problem.

Eg: t=3

```
min cost
st constraint[1]
   constraint[2]
   constraint[3]
```

The solver I am using is `GLPK` and it solves the opt. problem using the simplex algorithm. With the below picture it is clear that the solver takes up more time when you have bigger values of t (timesteps). And it rises exponentially.

I would like to find a reason for that. I mean it makes of course sense that it takes more time to solve the opt. problem, but what I am wondering is why it is exponential and not linear. The reason is most likely because of the effects of the complexity of the opt. problem over the simplex algorithm.

**Is there any paper that I could read about the calculation efficiency on the simplex algo, or a paper which explains why the calculation time is exponentially rising?**

Any hints would be very beneficial, ty!

[image: ger]

Comment: The worst case complexity of the simplex algorithm is exponential : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Efficiency

Comment: @Kuifje yes I can see that from the results already and okey wikipedia says the same thing. But the question is why?

Comment: The short answer is : you can generate a polygon with $O(2^n)$ vertices, and the simplex may need to visit each of these vertices before reaching the optimal one, hence an exponential number of iterations.

Comment: The `oemof` curve with the orange dots looks like a parabola. You might want to calculate a polynomial approximation to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments above -- you cannot conclude that the CPU time is increasing exponentially just by eyeballing it. It might just as easily be quadratic or other polynomial.

What I think you are really asking is, *why does the CPU time increase faster than linearly*? The short answer is, the simplex method uses operations that require more than a linear number of operations, such as matrix inversion. So, as the number of variables, $n$, increases, the number of operations increases faster than $n$. Even if the number of simplex iterations were to stay the same as $n$ increases (which it probably wouldn't), the CPU time would increase faster than linearly. This is true of most optimization algorithms.